# Pandas histogram with legend

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram

My dataframe looks like this:

| Customer ID | Age | Is True |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 31 | 1 |
| 124 | 33 | 1 |
| 125 | 45 | 0 |
| 126 | 27 | 0 |
| 127 | 37 | 1 |
| 128 | 39 | 0 |
| 129 | 49 | 0 |
| 130 | 30 | 0 |
| 131 | 30 | 0 |
| 132 | 38 | 1 |

I can create age histogram like this:

```
df.Age.hist()
plt.title('Age')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

And I will get:

[image]

I would like to add a legend of the 'Is True' field. For each Bin, I would like to see what portion is 1. How can I do that?

Comment: Then you don't want an histogram, the bins might mix both categories

Comment: @mozway, not sure I understood. I would like to see it stacked. for which bin, part of it is 1, part 0

Comment: OK I see, Can you still provide a schematic for clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that with Matplotlib. But I know you can with Plotly.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color="sex")
fig.show()
```

[image]

more here:
https://plotly.com/python/histograms/